# Password remember does not work as needed

Tags: c#, asp.net

On the website I am working on it has been deployed but the problem I am facing is that when I enter a username and password and click on the check box to remember...It remembers the password for sometime.. wen I login in after 5 or 10 minutes it remembers the password but aftr a long period of time like about 2hours it forgets the username and password and i have to type it in all over again... this dint used to happen with the old server as even I could sign in and it remembered the password the next day until i log off... what can be the reason

The session state im using is:

Comment: Could it be that you had configured a different session timeout? Do you save the password in the browser or do you use a cookie-based mechanism?

Comment: what is the 'duration' of your cookie (how long should they be saved)?

Comment: I have no idea wat is a web-farm...???? 
this is in my web config
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="5"/>

Comment: That would only be applicable if you're storing the user/password in session.  It's a different issue if you're saving it in a cookie.

Comment: It is saving in a cookie

Comment: Then my guess would be that you're not setting the cookie expiration date correctly (as KevinDTimm mentioned)

Comment: how do i have to set the cookie expiration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are facing time-out issues.

That is, you enter the site, and then walk away for some time, and come back, and the site has "forgotten" you, it doesn't know what to do, so it logs you out.

You can fix this by making your Session Timeout longer.

[Here's more info and how to do it.](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/07/aspnet-session-timeouts.html)

If this is indeed the case, there's nothing wrong with your 'Remember Me" function.

Comment: so what can i do to make it remember my password until i log out

<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="5"/>

Comment: it doesnt give me any session time  out error its just that it doesnt remember the login details that is the username and password

Comment: @sweetsecret - You should have read that link. >_o We really think it is the timeout issue. From the code you just posted, your timeout is set to 5 minutes. That is, if you walk away from your computer for 5 minutes with the application still up in your browser, it will time out. 5 minutes bad for you, and I believe either 30 or 60 is the standard. Try increasing this time. The biggest it can be is the number of hours in a year.

Comment: @sweetsecret - Also, the timeout value is in minutes. And you should really comprehend Session Timeouts, as it is something you will always battle with as an ASP.NET developer - and if not you personally, certainly your users, and you will be thus better able to answer/handle their questions and problems. = )

Answer (score 0):

Is this setting the cookie expire period??? I am confused

function rememberStyle( cookieName, cookieLife ) {

```
for( var viewUsed = false, ss = getAllSheets(), x = 0; window.MWJss && MWJss[x] && ss[x]; x++ ) { if( ss[x].disabled != MWJss[x] ) { viewUsed = true; break; } }
if( !window.userHasChosen && !viewUsed ) { return; }
for( var x = 0, outLine = '', doneYet = []; ss[x]; x++ ) {
    if( ss[x].title && ss[x].disabled == false && !doneYet[ss[x].title] ) { doneYet[ss[x].title] = true; outLine += ( outLine ? ' MWJ ' : '' ) + escape( ss[x].title ); } }
if( ss.length ) { document.cookie = escape( cookieName ) + '=' + escape( outLine ) + ( cookieLife ? ';expires=' + new Date( ( new Date() ).getTime() + ( cookieLife * 86400000 ) ).toGMTString() : '' ) + ';path=/'; }
```

}

Comment: Eewy, goodness, no. ASP.NET handles cookies magically for you. There is usually no reason to manually edit cookies.

Comment: I am glad to see that you are learning so much ASP.NET hands-on! Sometimes it can be more of a dunk rather than step-by-step when troubleshooting problems.